# Difference between Ribbon circuit breaker and Hystrix

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix, netflix, netflix-ribbon

I'm giving a try to Spring Cloud and Spring Boot. It uses Netflix OSS Applications, among them there are Ribbon and Hystrix.

Ribbon is a load balancer and comes with some features, one of them is a circuit breaker.

Hystrix is a circuit breaker application.

I don't know the difference between them both. Why use Hystrix if Ribbon already comes with a circuit breaker feature.

Can I use both applications in the same connector?

Answer (score 14):

I'm not aware of any circuit breaker in ribbon except integration with Hystrix. We recommend using both, ribbon for the load balancer and hystrix for the circuit breaker.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is taken from the Ribbon site. 

https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/wiki/Features#built-in-failure-resiliency

And

https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/wiki/Working-with-load-balancers#availabilityfilteringrule

It isn't a perfect circuit braker, but it can do the job.

Comment: The Circut breaker pattern involve a lot more than just checking if a server is up, and moving on to the next if it is not. Probing (sending some reqiests through), autorecovery, robust and predictable fault handling etc.

Comment: @spencergibb Is there a place where I can find how ribbon & hystrix integrate. Some load balancing `IRule`s like `AvailabilityFilteringRule` does limited circuit breaking (by load balancing the uprequests only among the servers that look alive, if none look alive, throws an exception [maybe?]). Can you explain how ribbon handles non 200 responses & cascade that info to hystrix (is it by explicitly throwing exception?)

Comment: Could you clarify who is the "we" in "we recommend"? Thanks :)